# Converting C++ Application with MSVC 2015 community's cross-platform tool set?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cross-platform, vs-community-edition

I am attempting to take a fairly large existing c++ application and make an APK out of it as to have it run on android architectures, which requires the C++ code to be wrapped with the JNI or to be re-written in java. I have been researching how to accomplish the first option.

In my research i have come across two articles that have me a bit worried about the whole process. [Article one](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-code-in-an-android-app-with-the-ndk/) shortly talks about the complexity and resulting performance loss that wrapping my c++ code with the JNI will warrant. [Article two](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-free-app-that-will-build-my-c++-programs-to-apk-in-android-phone) (all be it a poor article IMHO) makes me even more worried about the process.

**The Process:**

Build all of the dependencies of my C++ application into static or sharied libraries.

Wrap existing code with JNI.

Eventually use the Android NDK (much like Cmake or make) to build the APK i so desperately seek.

The main question that i have is does the MSVC 2015 cross-platform toolset/IDE/whatever you want to call it make this whole process easier? i know that the cross-platform tool uses the ndk to do essentially the same thing i am doing by hand, but how and where does the JNI come into the cross-platform tools? Can i just try and take my current solution and import it into a cross platform solution, black magic ensues, and out pops my APK? Or does the cross-platform functionality not effect the process i am currently attempting?

(as this is a new account i cannot post all of the links i wish to, i am sorry)